# What does the notation $Dx(a-bi-x)$ mean?

Tags: polynomials, derivatives, notation

Sorry for completely newbie question, but could not the answer anywhere else. On the Wikipedia page about "[Steiner inellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse)" there is the following notation equating roots of cubic polynomial and roots of its derivative:

$Dx(1 + 7i − x)(7 + 5i − x)(3 + i − x) = (13/3 + 11/3i − x)(3 + 5i − x).$

What does the 'Dx' symbol mean here?

Comment: Go to the page again and click on "Marden's Theorem" for more information about relating the inellipse's foci to its complex vertices.

Comment: The leading order term of the derivative should be $-3x^2$ though, so something does not quite fit; probably a factor of $(-3)$ is missing.

Comment: Probably should be $D_x$, but the caption of a figure does not admit Latex.

Comment: For those confused by the wording of the question: I've edited the Wikipedia article to have the $x$ as a subscript, as well as added the missing $-3$.

Comment: @fuglede Nice, beat me to it :)

Comment: @ChristopherErnst, Thanks for the answer. I thought that roots of derivative somehow can be obtained directly from the cubic roots. But one need to do a usual differentiantion.

Comment: My pleasure to help.

Comment: @rschwieb, i deleted the comment and reposted as the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the page: "According to Marden's theorem,[3] if the three vertices of the triangle are the complex zeros of a cubic polynomial, then the foci of the Steiner inellipse are the zeros of the derivative  of the polynomial."

The Dx symbol means that the derivative of the cubic polynomial $$((1+7i)−x)((7+5i)−x)((3+i)−x)$$  is $$-3((13/3+11/3i)−x)((3+5i)−x)$$